# Stretching element via CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a simple calculator app and I need to stretch those elements (circled red) without moving the whole calculator or its buttons. 
I can't figure it out myself due to low experience.

[image]

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.main-calc {
  background-color: #333;
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px gold;
}

.display {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 48px;
  background-color: azure;
  border: 5px solid green;
}

.buttons-block {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 5fr 2fr;
  background-color: rgb(132, 132, 132);
  margin-top: 15%;
  height: 80%;
}

.nums-btns {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  align-content: space-evenly;
  border: 5px solid red;
  /* height: 100%;
    width: 80%; */
}

.nums-btns:only-child(zero) {}

.btn {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
}

.action-btns {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  align-content: space-evenly;
  justify-items: center;
  border: 5px solid red;
  /* height: 100%;
    width: 20%; */
}
```

```html
<div class="main-calc">
  <div class="display">
    <p>0</p>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons-block">
    <div class="nums-btns">
      <button class="btn">7</button>
      <button class="btn">8</button>
      <button class="btn">9</button>
      <button class="btn">4</button>
      <button class="btn">5</button>
      <button class="btn">6</button>
      <button class="btn">1</button>
      <button class="btn">2</button>
      <button class="btn">3</button>

      <button class="btn zero">0</button>
      <button class="btn equal">=</button>
    </div>
    <div class="action-btns">
      <button class="btn">+</button>
      <button class="btn">-</button>
      <button class="btn">*</button>
      <button class="btn">/</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I did try to put those elements in a different div, but it broke my whole calculator and I can't find where I am bad at.
I was doing width bigger but this way it stretched the space above my 'zero' button.
I tried to use some pseudo-classes in CSS but it didn't help cause I'm not really sure how to apply it

Comment: Stretch them how. What is this supposed to look like? Perhaps - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/NWJZNyq

Comment: As a side-note, calculators have a normed layout and you miss the decimal point. You might want to fix that. Beside that, `grid-column: span 2` on the equals button will help you. If you already use a grid, then sue the grid for the entire calculator not 3 sub grids